# C# SQL Syntax Error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, syntax

Can anyone tell me why when I try to add a field into this SQL Server database I get the error

> Incorrect Syntax near the keyword 'Table'.

Code:

```
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'tBoxDataSet.Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.tBoxDataSet.Table);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(global::TicketBox.Properties.Settings.Default.TBoxConnectionString);
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(global::TicketBox.Properties.Settings.Default.TBoxConnectionString))
            using (SqlCommand runsql = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Table (Event_ID,Artist,Venue,Date,Time,Tickets) values(@EventID,@Artist, @Venue, @Date, @Time,@Tickets)", connect))
            {
                runsql.Parameters.Add("@EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;
                runsql.Parameters.Add("@Artist", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
                runsql.Parameters.Add("@Venue", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
                runsql.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = textBox4.Text;
                runsql.Parameters.Add("@Time", SqlDbType.Time).Value = textBox5.Text;
                runsql.Parameters.Add("@Tickets", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox6.Text;
                connect.Open();
                runsql.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Event Added", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            this.tableTableAdapter.Fill(this.tBoxDataSet.Table);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I think 'Table' is a keyword. do you actualy have a table called 'Table'? I suggest you rename it to 'Concerts' or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Table` and `Time` are [reserved keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in T-SQL. You need to use them with square brackets like `[Table]` and `[Time]`.

As a best practice, change them to *non-reserved* words.

Also `Date` can be a reserved keyword in future releases of SQL Server. You might need to use it with square brackets as well.

Comment: I cant believe I forgot that, been looking at this too long. Thanks fixed :)

Comment: Databases can be case sensitive; it the OP calls the table `Table`, it should be `[Table]` - not `[TABLE]`, which can be an entirely different table ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell Exactly. Even their case are different, both `Table` and `TABLE` are behaves as reserved word. But yes, I edited to based on OP's original column names. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if your table name is TABLE, then.. that is a keyword for sql...

change your query to

INSERT INTO [Table]

using [ ] will override the keyword

Answer (score 0):

> as Tabel is a reserved keyword , you need to use like this [table]

change the query to.

```
INSERT INTO [Table] (Event_ID,Artist,Venue,Date,Time,Tickets)  
values(@EventID,@Artist, @Venue, @Date, @Time,@Tickets)
```